# Refuse to download non-php files

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want my server to refuse to view and download all non-php files, So i wrote this code in "nginx.conf":

[image]

I restarted the server, did some testing, and found that it didn't work.  Where is the mistake, please?

Comment: Asd code as text into question. Show complete nginx config

Comment: I've changed the way,and it works very well now.Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a negate block you can use something like below

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass ...;
        ....;
    }
}
```